# Error loading templatetags from a Django application

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-tagging

I'm trying to load the templatetags included with the [django-tagging](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-tagging/) application (django-tagging templatetags [docs](http://django-tagging.readthedocs.io/en/develop/#template-tags) don't specify what the load statement should be) but I'm getting a TemplateSyntax error reminding me to load or register the tag - which I'm pretty sure I've done.

Here's the relevant section of my template

```
1   {% extends "base_tags.html" %}
2   
3   {% load staticfiles %}
4   {% load coltrane_tags %}
5   {% load tagging_tags %)
6   
7   <div class="row">
8   
9     {% block content %}
10    <div class="col-md-9">
11      {% tags_for_model coltrane.Entry as entry_tags %}
12      {% for obj in entry_tags %}
13        {{ obj }}
14      {% endfor %}
..    </div>
..    {% endblock %}
..  </div>
```

The error message is:

> Invalid block tag on line 11: 'tags_for_model', expected 'endblock'.
>   Did you forget to register or load this tag?

Looking at the django-tagging module I can see the templatetags code:

```
<PythonVirtualEnv>/site-packages/tagging/templatetags/tagging_tags.py
```

The tag I'd like to use is registered in this file:

```
register.tag('tags_for_model', do_tags_for_model)
```

So from my perspective it's both registered and loaded - is there anything obvious that I'm missing?

Comment: Are you ever closing your content block with ```{% endblock content %}```?

Comment: Yes, the template was quite long so I didn't include everything. I've edited though to make clearer.